# Xamarin.forms] I want to prevent other items in the ListView from clicking when ContextActions is Active

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, contextmenu, menuitem, android-context

When ContextActions is active on an Android device, you can click another item in the ListView to activate the ContextActions of other items.

I would like to prevent other touches other than ContextActions so that I can not select another Item after activating ContextActions by long-clicking the Item in the ListView.

The scenario I think is:
1. Activate the ContextActions of the Item by long-clicking the Item in the ListView.
2. If an event with ContextActions enabled is present, the touch event of the ListView is no longer disabled for that event.
3. When ContextActions is finished, it receives the event again and activates the touch event of the ListView.

For this scenario I need to know when list items are long-clicked or when ContextActions is enabled.

I need help.
Thank you :)